# Equivalent of pdb.runcall in Pycharm debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I use pdb.runcall to check if a function behaves as I expected. However, it does not have the visual component as IDE debuggers like Pycharm's. Can I do the same thing with Pycharm debugger without running the whole program from the beginning? I want to debug a specific function by using my current environment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, we can attach a debugger to the console with a button on the console menu (green bug to the left of the console). If we place a breakpoint in the module or function we want to step into and call the function normally the debugger lands on the breakpoint like the normal debugger. But, with the console debugger, I was able to use the variables in my environment without running the whole application.